# Refresh html DIv in Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

i am trying to refresh an {%extends%} page since my base.html is getting message information from whatever is happening in the python backend, it only shows the message after i refresh my page and i want to refresh it every x seconds so the alerts will show without needing to refresh my entire page.

```
    <div id="Mydiv">
{% extends 'crodlUSDT/base.html'%}
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        function refresh()
        {
            var div = $('#Mydiv'),
                divHtml = div.html();

            div.html(divHtml);
        }

        setInterval(function()
        {
            refresh()
        }, 3000); //300000 is 5minutes in ms
    })
</script>
```

this is what i've found online but tested a lot of different things but none are working, is this possible ?
thanks

ive also tried doing this inside of my html file

```
    <div id="messages" class="messages">
    {% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
    <div class = "alert alert-{{message.tags}}">{{message}}</div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
            function refresh()
            {
                var div = $('#messages'),
                    divHtml = div.html();
    
                div.html(divHtml);
            }
    
            setInterval(function()
            {
                refresh()
            }, 3000); //300000 is 5minutes in ms
        })
    </script>
```

but also only shows the message after page refresh

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working", please? In what way is it not working -- what are you expecting to happen and what's actually happening? In this case, it appears you're replacing the HTML with itself, so no change is visible. Pick some new HTML for the div.

Comment: HI , what i want to happen is the div that holds the message to refresh , so base.html is my navbar where the message loads and my current page is syntax.html so when i am in syntax.html i want to refresh the navbar with base.html receiving the message so that when there is a new message the user will be able to see it and it without having to refresh the syntax.html page itself